# POSTing JSON with GuzzleHttp\Client: returning 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: php, json, guzzle6

I'm trying to create a wrapper for a payment gateway api. I've chosen to use `GuzzleHttp`. Here is the basic code that I currently have. As the gateway expects input to be JSON formatted sent via HTTP POST, I tried two possible ways:

1. Using the `json` option and assigning a key-based array to it.
2. Explicitly setting `content-type` to `application/json` and sending a json formatted string via `body`.

**Code:**

```
$client = new Client([
          'base_uri' => 'https://sandbox.gateway.com',
]);

$input = [
        'merchant_id' => '12345-33445',
        'security_key' => '**********',
        'operation' => 'ping',
    ];


$clientHandler = $client->getConfig('handler');
$tapMiddleware = Middleware::tap(function ($request) {
    foreach($request->getHeaders() as $h=>$v){
        echo $h . ': ' . print_r($v) . PHP_EOL;
    }
});

try {
    $response = $client->post(
        '/pg/auth',
        [
            'timeout' => 30,
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Cache-Control' =>  'no-cache',
            ],
            'body' => json_encode($input),
            'debug' => true,
            'handler' => $tapMiddleware($clientHandler)
        ]
    );

    print_r($response);
} catch(Exeption $e){
    print_r($e);
}
```

Unfortunately, gateway got back with a 401 error although the credentials are correct. I suspect the way request is sent has an issue. I came to this conclusion as the headers printed from within the `tap` function are all `arrays` (especially `content-type`) instead of strings. Unlike what is described here `http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html?highlight=request#json`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => GuzzleHttp/6.1.1 curl/7.43.0 PHP/5.5.29
)
User-Agent: 1
Array
(
    [0] => sandbox.gateway.com
)
Host: 1
Array
(
    [0] => application/json
)
Content-Type: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about sending the request as suggested?

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://sandbox.gateway.com',
]);

$client->request('POST', '/pg/auth', [
    'timeout' => 30,
    'debug' => true,
    'json' => [
        'merchant_id' => '12345-33445',
        'security_key' => '**********',
        'operation' => 'ping',
    ],
]);
```

For reference, see http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json.

Comment: Tried that as well. Same thing. Looks like that is exactly how headers are sent and now I wonder why the documentation doesn't cover it.